# Radar chart color inner circles

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, charts

Is it possible to color the inner circles of a radar chart. I want to color each section differently
The image below should clarify:

[Wanted radar chart](http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/2483/imagethumb.png)

Answer (score 0):

The more "correct, general-purpose" and efficient way is probably Graphics.FillPath().

But it's probably less code to use FillEllipse() to draw your filled circles from the outside in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I should have mentioned i'm using the standard ASP.NET Charting controls.
So i don't know i FillEllipse works with that, will check!